# Can I export service constants via "x typescript" command?

Tags: typescript, servicestack

I have a search service and I would like the "default search query" constant to be exported to typescript for use in some clients.

I have the following line in my .cs DTO

`public string DefaultQuery { get; set; } = "default query";`

But when I inspect my dto.ts it appears like this:

`public defaultQuery: string;`

Is there a way to get the value to come through rather than just a type definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, translated DTOs only capture the Type definitions of the API contract, they don’t contain any behavior.